# Load 2 layer in one base map geonetwork

Tags: geoserver, wms, geonetwork

i want to load 2 layers from geonetwork in one basemap on geonetwork !! so my question turn about how to configurate the file config-viewer.xml to support 2 arguments name  in the same ows-context:Layer

Comment: Does a single GetMap request not work? 'Layers=bottom-layer, top-layer&'

Comment: for one layer it works perfectly , but i want to load 2 layer :   <ows-context:Layer queryable="true" name="Monde"
                        hidden="false" opacity="1"
                        group="Background layers">
            <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows">Carte Monde</ows:Title>
            
                <ows-context:OnlineResource xlink:href="http://105.0.0.3:8080/geoserver/wms?"/>
            </ows-context:Server
        </ows-context:Layer>if you have a way or an example to do it it will be nice from ur part

Comment: Why not set a group layer in geoserver and then use the group layer as the single base layer

Comment: yes i think that it is useful , just i wondring if i can add 2 layers from geonetwork !!

Comment: If the two layers are from the same service I would try, as per my first comment, to see where the layers name is defined and instead of one layer name give two layer comma separated names.  So perhaps that would be `<ows-context:Layer queryable="true" name="Monde,layer two"...>`,   It would be useful to know what actual XML schema is used or referenced by ` <ows-contex..` as OGC doesn't seem to have one.  If you can find what's allowed by the schema then perhaps you can find a way.

Comment: This way is already tested without any results , i will try to figure out a solution and then i will share my feedback  !!

Comment: i have tried the group layer on geoserver  but an error occured that the noun of "group" layer doesn't found !! i think that ows context point on layers warehouse  but the group of layer is located on aggregate layer , have you ever tested thsi issues